# Locally integrable function in Lebesgue sense

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

Let $a(x):\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$ be locally integrable function in Lebesgue sense and
$$A(x)=\int_{0}^{x}a(t)\,dt.$$

In which conditions on $a$, $A^\prime(x)=a(x)$ holds.

Comment: This holds true whenever $a$ is continuous.

Comment: Note the [Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) - in particular the 1-dimensional version discussed at the end of the Statement section. The use of $-\infty$ instead of $0$ as the lower limit is easily gotten around by multiplying by $\mathbf 1_{[0,\infty)}$. But understand that the "almost everywhere" condition applies not only to $F$ being differentiable, but also to $F'(x) = f(x)$. (i.e., it is possible for $F'(x)$ to exist, but not equal $f(x)$).

Comment: As I understand, if $a(x):\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$ is locally integrable function in Lebesgue sense (in 1-dimensional case), then $A$ is  almost everywhere differentiable and $A'(x)=a(x)$. I do not need to suppose any condition on $a(x)$

Comment: or we still need to suppose $a(x)$ is continuous